# Memory in if condition

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Ok, this is a hard question for me to ask, to make you udnerstand what I want to know

So assume this pseudo code :

```
While(true)

if(boolean is true)

else

End While
```

Ok, with this, I have a while who,s always running, what I wonder is if there's anyway to enter the if without re valuating  the boolean each time, also you need to know the boolean may change but never in the if itself.

I know it seems crazy thinking, I just wonder if it's possible to enter a condition without evaluating it, IF the condition was true the time before.

***EDIT***

Also I'm imaginating this idea from an electric cicuit, imagine a switch if the contact is made the electricity will go straith to the light else it woN't pass but it doN,t really check wich way it just assume where he can go, I know I,m really confusing :S

***EDIT 2***

Maybe this will be more clear ? i'm not sure

[image]

Comment: than what is the use of condition?

Comment: and what exactly u want ????

Comment: I know this question would come "what youw ant to do" , I want a condition who's evaluated every 10 second but I want to save some memory in the way if the precedent condition was true it WILL be this time to and in the if the boolean may change

Comment: How can the code tell if the switch is closed or not each time round, without checking it using another IF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because what you're asking for is "how do I branch without checking a condition?" and the answer is, you can't.

If the condition check is a complex operation then You can memorize the result of a condition check in a boolean variable, and branch on the variable.

However, in order to truely eliminate the branch in your example, the general pattern is to separate the true and false conditions to be outside the while loop:

```
 while(true)
 {
     if(condition) break;
 }
 while(true)
 {
     // condition was true 
 }
```

Comment: Well that did it I see now, and thank for telling me what I was looking for, as I said I didn't know myself :S but thank you sir

Answer (score -1):

Simple, just simply emit the if statement if you want it to pass its condition automatically.